# Problem with PSTricks: luatex85.sty' not found

Tags: luatex, pstricks, texstudio

I am trying to get PSTricks to work. I have installed PSTricks and changed the shell escape in TexStudio. Now I get the following error:
`File ´luatex85.sty' not found. \else`
I could not find anything useful via google.

Here is the latex-code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-intersect}

\begin{document}
    
    \psset{unit=2}
    \begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-0.5)(3,3)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(2.75,2.75)[$x$,-90][$y$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,plotpoints=51,linewidth=1.5pt}
    \pssavepath[linecolor=red!40]{Pa}{\psplot{0.15}{3}{1/x}}%
    \pssavepath[linecolor=blue!40]{Pb}{\psplot{0.15}{3}{2/x}}%
    \pssavepath[linecolor=green!40]{Pc}{\psplot{0}{3}{(x-1)*(x+1)}}%
    \pssavepath[linecolor=yellow]{Pd}{\psplot{0}{3}{(x-2)*(x+2)}}%
    \psintersect[name=A]{Pa}{Pc}\psintersect[name=B]{Pa}{Pd}
    \psintersect[name=C]{Pb}{Pc}\psintersect[name=D]{Pb}{Pd}
    \pscustom[fillcolor=magenta,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none]{%
        \psplot{\psGetIsectCenter{A}{}{1} I-A1.x}%
        {\psGetIsectCenter{C}{}{1} I-C1.x}{(x-1)*(x+1)}
        \psplot{\psGetIsectCenter{C}{}{1} I-C1.x}%
        {\psGetIsectCenter{D}{}{1} I-D1.x}{2/x}
        \psplot{\psGetIsectCenter{D}{}{1} I-D1.x}%
        {\psGetIsectCenter{B}{}{1} I-B1.x}{(x-2)*(x+2)}
        \psplot{\psGetIsectCenter{B}{}{1} I-B1.x}%
        {\psGetIsectCenter{A}{}{1} I-A1.x}{1/x}
    }
    \end{pspicture*}
    
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: luatex85 is part of every current tex system. You can install it with whatever package manager you have.